# exclude files from angular 4 build

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

how can i confirm that files are excluded after the build?

My tsconfig.json file looks like this

```
 {
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "src/app/schemas/abc"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Are you using angular-cli?

Comment: Yes. I am using angular-cli.

Comment: Can you elaborate what is wrong and maybe post your config file? Please post your tsconfig.app.json

Comment: Please have a look. I have updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

It depends relatively on the location of the tsconfig file in your project. If your tsconfig file is in src/tsconfig then you are missing the baseUrl in the compiler options, and you should include the path like this.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": { 
   "baseUrl": ".",
   ....
 },
  "exclude": [
    "schemas/abc",
    "./app/schemas/abc/"
  ]
}
```

This will exclude all files in schemas/abc/ when you compile.